# Install new Android OS?

Tags: custom-roms, operating-system

I bought a new Chinese phone which they said I could use with T-Mobile. The IMEI was not acceptable by T-Mobile. It is supposed to be Android 12, but when I try to download (WiFi) some apps from Google Play Store, it won't even find some common apps (TextNow, ZUMIMALL). I attached 2 images of the phone specs.

[image: about phone]

At this point, I think I need to install a different Android OS. Is it possible? I am open to suggestions as to what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Cannot upgrade current android that came with phone it is custom. Would like to replace android OS.

Comment: Replacing is the same as upgrading. Typically for a china phone there are no upgrade, updates or alternative versions.

Comment: Unfortunately the phone is useless now.